# HikariDataSource configuration

Tags: java, hikaricp

I'm using HikariDataSource in my Java application. I'm very new to using it.

This is my configuration:

```
private DataSource buildDataSource(String dataSource, String url, String user, String password) {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setInitializationFailTimeout(0);
        dataSource.setMinimumIdle(1);
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
        dataSource.setIdleTimeout(300000);
        dataSource.setMaxLifetime(900000);
        dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
        dataSource.setDataSourceClassName(dataSource);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("url", url);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("user", user);
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Here I have `MaximumPoolSize` as 1. And when I run the application, this connection will usually be idle:

I want to understand

1. How many requests can be handled by one connection in a second.
2. Whether one connection can accept and process multiple requests in parallel, or other requests have to wait until the previous request gets completed?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Why are you capping the pool size to just 1?

Comment: Hi akortex
I'm running this application in UI environment. and only few people are using it(3 people).

Comment: 1) depends on the queries 2) One at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using a connection pool with just one connection is a bit counter-intuitive. The whole purpose of having a connection pool is to have multiple connections available (or in use) at any given time, thus allowing your application to quickly attain one without the extra cost of creating it.

Since your use case calls for a single connection, I do not see the point of using a connection pool. To answer your questions:

1. It depends on how long your requests (i.e queries take to execute against your database).
2. As long as the connection is allocated to a thread, then every other caller will hung waiting for the connection to be returned to the pool.

Based on your use case, I think there is no need to use connection pooling. If you want to operate with a single connection simply create it, use it and finally discard it. On the other hand if you want to operate using multiple connections at any given moment, then go ahead and configure your connection pool to include more available connections.